# Mistake to send Ethers

Tags: contract-development, resend

When sending funds (Ether) from my main wallet, I entered my own address and sent them to myself. This created a contract with my funds. Is there any way to recover the funds?
Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that your ether is gone.

If I'm not mistaken, this is the transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x60a19be9e395189a09a02ac74aefba0748b49c21eec3691ffa970b7880ed6976.

It doesn't look like you sent ether to yourself; you sent it to address 0. Transactions sent to address 0 create smart contracts. Since you didn't provide any code (because you weren't actually trying to create a smart contract), the smart contract can't do anything, so it's going to exist like this forever with that ether locked inside.

Here's a link to the smart contract you created: https://etherscan.io/address/0x514d9d1c7d86bff4ccab4fb7eba8783f3bf4b0aa. Note that its code is empty.